# Botão executando shell script

Tags: qt, qtgui

Ao clicar no botão Salvar, queria que o conteúdo da caixa de texto (que eu digitei ou colei em *plain text*) fosse inserido no final de um determinado arquivo de texto que existe na minha home.

Esse processo eu faço atualmente com o seguinte script no terminal:

```
folder=/mnt/dados/Dropbox
file=$folder/rascunho
content=$1
printf "\n\n" >> $file
echo "------< $(date "+%b %d, %Y - %H:%M:%S") >------" >> $file
echo "$1" >> $file
```

Ou seja, sempre no mesmo arquivo, inserindo no final dele uma linha com data e hora e abaixo o conteúdo que passei pro script.

Agora, queria poder digitar esse conteúdo na área de texto da janela e usar o botão Salvar para inseri-lo no arquivo.

Comment: Por favor, na sua próxima pergunta, se restrinja ao que importa da sua questão. Por exemplo, não era necessário postar o arquivo `.ui`, uma vez que sua dúvida é sobre execução de processos, e não interface de usuário. Quanto menor e mais objetiva forem as perguntas, mais fácil e mais rápido de algum colaborador encontrar a resposta correta.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, obrigado pela observação. Mas como não tenho a menor ideia do assunto, não soube se eram poucas ou muitas as minhas informações. Por isso, optei por colocar tudo. Obrigado.

Comment: Mas se é pra fazer append num arquivo, não é melhor fazer direto com C++ em vez de chamar um shell script?

Comment: @bfavaretto, desculpe, mas não tenho conhecimento para decidir o que é melhor. O que quero é tentar fazer um GUI para o meu famoso script `rascunho` que guarda tudo no arquivo de texto. Sempre que preciso guardar qualquer coisa, faço `rascunho "foo"` e pronto. Depois só faço um `cade "foo"` pra chamar o `grep` no rascunho.

Comment: Ok, entendo. Se o programa fosse todo em C++ faria mais sentido usar a própria linguagem para uma operação simples assim. Digo isso mesmo sem saber C++, mas escrever num arquivo é uma operação básica. Se for levar seu projeto mais adiante, vale considerar migrar todo o código para C++.

Comment: @bfavaretto, na verdade, tentei o Qt pois pensei que era com isso que os programas para Gnome fossem criados. Acabei de abrir o QtCreator e não tenho nem ideia de como usar.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize a classe `QProcess`. Como você não especificou a versão da Qt sendo utilizada, estou assumindo a versão 5.3.

Verifique se a primeira linha do script é `#!/bin/bash` para que o Linux decida *automagicamente* como executar o arquivo, e modifique o código abaixo para melhor atendê-lo:

```
QString program = "/path/to/the/script.sh"; // caminho do script.
QStringList arguments;
arguments << this->ui->texto->text(); // argumentos passados para o script.

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
myProcess->start(program, arguments); // executa o script.
myProcess->waitForFinished(-1); // aguarda a finalização do processo.
delete myProcess; // nada de memory leaks!
```

A documentação da Qt é excelente. Recomendo ler sobre a classe `QProcess` para tirar o máximo proveito dela:

[Qt 5.3 QProcess Class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html)

**Mais detalhes sobre Qt**

Qt é um framework por vezes classificado como abstração do sistema operacional. Isso vem do fato de que ela não apenas abstrai janelas e botões, como permite realizar diversas tarefas de baixo nível com completa portabilidade entre sistemas.

O visual é apenas um dos muitos pontos fortes da Qt, e é um bocado assustador quando se vem de outros mundos como .Net ou Delphi (que era o meu caso hehehe).

Na Qt, os arquivos com extensão `.ui` nada mais são que um arquivo XML que descreve seu formulário, de modo que quando sua aplicação é executada o mesmo formulário criado durante o design é criado pela Qt na execução, conservando, inclusive, as conexões entre os objetos. Enfim, o arquivo `.ui` nada mais é do que essa descrição detalhada da interface gráfica.

Porém, apesar de conectar os vários componentes utilizados no formulário, a função deste arquivo acaba aí. Por exemplo, quando um botão é clickado, o arquivo `.ui` diz que um método deve ser executado, porém a implementação do método não fica no arquivo `.ui`.

Acredito que esteja desenvolvendo em C++ com a QtCreator (se não estiver, recomendo fortemente!). Note que além do arquivo com extensão `.ui`, existem outros dois arquivos com a extensão `.h` e `.cpp`. Agora, vou assumir que você sabe o básico de programação em C++.

Seu projeto, então, deve ter os seguintes arquivos (corro o risco de a minha memória falhar, pois costumo não implementar minhas interfaces dentro do arquivo `.ui`):

```
main.cpp
MainWindow.ui
MainWindow.h
MainWindow.cpp
```

**main.cpp**

Apenas inicia a sua aplicação, criando o formulário principal da mesma e executando o loop de eventos. Normalmente, não mechemos neste arquivo, mas se quiser criar uma splash screen ou iniciar o formulário maximizado, teremos que alterar algumas coisas nele (não é o objetivo da questão então não vou detalhar além disso).

**MainWindow.h**

Possui a declaração dos signals, slots e demais membros do seu formulário. Estes são responsáveis por gerar o comportamento desejado do seu formulário.

**MainWindow.cpp**

Implementação dos métodos e slots (não deixam de ser métodos) declarados no arquivo `.h`.

Agora que já detalhei um pouco como funciona a Qt, vamos partir para implementar a execução do script no seu formulário.

Para ficar claro, o que desejamos é executar este código quando um botão é clicado na sua interface.

Para isso, precisamos definir um comportamento para quando o botão for clickado. Isto é feito conectando um `slot` ao sinal `clicked` do botão. Se estiver utilizando a QtCreator, basta clickar com o botão direito do mouse sobre o botão desejado, selecionar a opção `Go to slot` e selecionar o slot `clicked()`.

Ao fazer isso, repare que foi declarado um método no arquivo `MainWindow.h` e declarada a implementação deste método no arquivo `MainWindow.cpp`. Agora, precisamos apenas adicionar o código para executar o shell script no método que foi criado dentro do arquivo `MainWindow.cpp`.

Você terá algo mais ou menos assim:

```
void MainWindow::pushButton1_clicked() {
}
```

Dentro deste método você irá inserir o código que postei anteriormente:

```
void MainWindow::pushButton1_clicked() {
    QString program = "/path/to/the/script.sh"; // caminho do script.
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << this->ui->texto->text(); // argumentos passados para o script.

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start(program, arguments); // executa o script.
    myProcess->waitForFinished(-1); // aguarda a finalização do processo.
    delete myProcess; // nada de memory leaks!
}
```

Agora, basta substituir o caminho do script no local marcado, verificar se o `QLineEdit` com o texto a ser inserido no arquivo é realmente o `ui->texto`, compilar e rodar!

Tentei ser o mais breve possível, mas cobrindo os principais pontos necessários para realizar esta tarefa na Qt. Sobre a classe `QProcess` verifique a documentação. Pode parecer um pouco rude recomendar isso, mas é que o código é bastante direto, e a Qt é sem dúvida um dos frameworks com a melhor documentação (na minha opinião, melhor até que o .Net se desconsiderarmos os exemplos).

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ual... solução bem elaborada, muito mais complexa do que imaginei. Mas como comecei hoje a tentar aprender sobre Qt, não tenho ideia do que fazer com o seu código. Desculpe, mas poderia comentar aqui onde salvo seu código? Seria no mesmo `ui`?

Comment: Rapaz, quanta coisa! Obrigado pela primeira aula de Qt. Pra um matemático, é informação demais num dia só... Estou no note agora e baixando o 5.3. Nem sabia que precisava desses outros arquivos. Na verdade, no outro micro, abri o QtDesign e vi que havia chance de eu conseguir fazer uma janela pro meu shell script. Comecei a desenhar os objetos mas não tinha menor ideia de como fazer isso virar um programa. Valeu. Vou tentar aprender.

Comment: Legal! Boa sorte nos estudos! \m/

Comment: Opa. valeu. Estou seguindo um exemplo do Help pra fazer um FindText. Você tem um tempinho livre pra me ajudar com o exemplo? Se puder, podemos usar o chat.

Comment: Já já vou dormir, pois trampo amanhã, mas me adiciona no Facebook e o que eu puder ajudar eu ajudo: Vinicius Gobbo Antunes de Oliveira.